# Load Custom UiTableView as a ChildViewController in custom TabBarNavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm trying to incorporate `XLMailBox`, Custom ViewController as a parent viewController that can switch between different **childViewController** using a TabBar.

I'm loading a Custom `UITableViewController`
 called `SwipeTableViewController` as a **childViewController** within a parent viewController 
I use this code to load the `ParentViewController` in `AppDelegate` as `RootViewController`:

```
@implementation SwipeTableAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
SwipeTableViewController * child_1 = [[SwipeTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

NSArray * childViewControllers = @[child_1];
XLSwipeContainerController * containerController = [[XLSwipeContainerController alloc] initWithViewControllers:childViewControllers];
self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:containerController];

return YES;
```

}

### The SwipeTableViewController loads the table view as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    patternImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"neon-autumn.gif", @"alchemy.jpg", @"white-wood.jpg", @"green-goblin.png", @"subway-lines.png", @"canvas-orange.jpg", @"kiwis.png", @"cuadros.png", @"hodgepodge.png", @"naranjas.png", @"bunting-flag.png", nil];
    self.title = @"Rounds";
    _patients = [RND_PatientDB loadScaryBugDocs];
   [self.tableView registerClass:[CustomTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
NSLog(@"FirstViewController - viewDidLoad");

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                              initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                              target:self action:@selector(addTapped:)];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

       static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    RND_Patient *patients = [self.patients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    cell.patternImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[patternImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.patternLabel.text = patients.data.ptName;
    cell.ptDesc.text = patients.data.ptDesc;
    cell.ptNumber.text = patients.data.ptNumber;

    if (patients.data.completed == 1){
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

It then configures the cell using the `CustomTableViewCell` class and populates with data from `RND_Patients` **mutablearray** which it loads initially.
Now my problem is that when I load the `SwipeTableViewController` as a **childViewController**, the cells are empty and are not populated with data.
When I load directly the `SwipeTableViewController` as part of the `RootViewController` without using the `XLMailBox` custom navigation controller, the table view loads just fine and has the appropriate cells and the appropriate data. 
I do not understand the discrepancy between these two views. All my code seems correct, but in my first example, the `CustomTableViewCell` does not load and in the second it loads. Any ideas on how can I fix this?

Comment: Where and how do you set the datasource and delegate for the tableView?

Comment: @pbasdf I load the datasource using the    method in the ViewDidLoad of SwipeTableViewController.m .I know the data source is loaded correctly, because if I set cell.textLabel = patients.data.ptName; it loads the cell textLabel correctly. The problem is I have a custom cell with three different kind of labels, and when I set those labels to the data in my NSMutableArray they do not show up. This leads me to believe that the UITableView is loaded as default and my custom UITableView and CustomTableViewCell are not loaded at all. Also the delegate is the first part of my code.

Comment: If you log [self.tableView class] in viewDidLoad, what does it show?